# WebGLBuffer object and OpenGL buffer handle interop between JavaScript and C++

Tags: javascript, c++, webgl, emscripten

I want to use spector.js [metadata API](https://github.com/BabylonJS/Spector.js/blob/master/readme.md#custom-data)  to simplify debugging of a WebGL application compiled from C++ using emscripten. Spector.js API expects JavaScript [WebGLBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLBuffer) objects created via WebGL API. The question is how to get them from the C++ side which operates with raw OpenGL handles.
I see two options:

1. Provide gl buffer handles to js via emscripten C++<->JS API and create WebGL objects from them somehow
2. Create WebGLBufers on the js side and provide handles to C++ via C++<->JS API

Problem with the first option is that I can't find a way to create a WebGLBuffer from a raw OpenGL buffer handle.
Problem with the second option is that I don't see any way to get a raw gl buffer handle from the js WebGLBuffer object to forward it to the C++ code.

Maybe there are also other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Augment the emscripten library. The WebGLObjects are tracked right here

https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/46df50cfd170521d91a31e0a74f2dfdeb4522968/src/library_webgl.js#L112

For example

```
  javascriptWebGLBuffer = $GL.buffers[openGLBufferId];
```

```
  openglBufferId = $GL.buffers.indexOf(javascriptWebGLBuffer);
```

also see [`_glGenObject`](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/46df50cfd170521d91a31e0a74f2dfdeb4522968/src/library_webgl.js#L1649) and [its usage](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/46df50cfd170521d91a31e0a74f2dfdeb4522968/src/library_webgl.js#L1673) on how to generate a new WebGLBuffer for both JavaScript and C++

You can plugin spector in that file.

You can use `--js-library path-to-file` to use your modified library to use it

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'll report asap when I've tried it.

Comment: Okay, I see how to inject spector there. But I don't really understand how to get access to $GL from the js library I add.

Comment: Without liooking into it deeper add a line `window.gl = $GL` in the library somewhere would be one solution

Comment: So modification of the emscripten js library is the way to do it. Not perfect, but it does the trick .Thank you.